# Change ViewPager Tabs to ImageViews:

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have implemented a `ViewPager` with `Tab`s using this tutorial:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

It works as I expected, but now I need to replace the `Tab`s with clickable `ImageView`s, Is there any simple way to do that?

this is the current result:

[image]

this is my current code:

**TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity:**

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener 
{
static final String TAG = "TabsActivity";
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
private ViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


/**
* Maintains extrinsic info of a tab's construct
*/
private class TabInfo 
{
    private String tag;
    private Class<?> clss;
    private Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) 
    {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }
}

/**
 * A simple factory that returns dummy views to the Tabhost
 */
class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.free_text_save_button_selector);
        return v;
    }
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
*/
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_screen_activity_layout);
    // Initialise the TabHost
    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager();
}


 /** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
private void intialiseViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));

    this.mPagerAdapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter:**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
private List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any view to your `Tabhost` as follows -

```
        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tag");
        ImageView indicator = new ImageView(activity.getBaseContext());
        indicator.setImageResource(R.id.tab_img);

        tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator);
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Remember to make `R.id.tab_img` a selector if you want to change the drawables for the selected and normal states as well.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I sorry for the stupid question. It's the first time I use ViewPager could you please explain where this code should go in the code I posted?

Comment: Well I have figured it out, Thanks for your help.

Comment: My apologies for not replying earlier. I'm glad I could help you.. :-)